# Turn off the "save changes" popup on modified files in Flash CS5.5 (JSFL)

Tags: flash, jsfl, flash-cs5.5

I'm using a jsfl script to run export to swf on about 200 fla files, this opens the fla file runs the commands from the jsfl then exports to SWF, however this modifies the FLA file and when it want to close the file from flash it asks me if I want to save the changes.

This is getting rather annoying since I'm hoping to make this automated.

Is there any way to turn of this feature in Flash CS5.5 premium.

perhaps a change in the JSFL file or a command line when starting the flash

Right now I'm doing

> %Path_TO_FLASH%\Flash.exe myscript.jsfl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error has been resolved.
See below.

Problem resided in the jsfl file

```
var doc = fl.openDocument(Filepath):
%Various commands%
doc.close(false); //this is a bool value for PromtSaveDialog default is "true"
```

I hope others who experiance the same issue will have some help from this